# JSONP ajax call to a restfull api

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, jsonp, laravel

I have searched for days and no one seems to have a definitive answer on this, i am begining to wonder if its a server/api issue and not an ajax one.

Any way i have built an API using Laravel 4. its dead simple nothing to complex. i have included the link below

[my question api](http://wld-api.eu1.frbit.net/index.php/api/v1/question/1)

basically it returns the following

```
{"error":false,"question":[{"id":1,"question_title":"Question 1","question_answer_a":"question1_answer_a","question_answer_b":"question1_answer_b","question_answer_c":"question1_answer_c","question_answer_d":"question1_answer_d","question_correct_answers":"a,b,c","question_explination":"question1_explinaition","question_meta":"question1_metadata","created_at":"2013-03-20 13:03:38","updated_at":"2013-03-20 17:30:10","status":1,"question_id":1,"image_url":"42ac1edf76f16924780df90ce5621476f7a263f7.jpg"}]}
```

Now i am working locally and in a simple html page i am using this ajax call to retrieve the api data

```
$.ajax({ 
         type: "GET",
         dataType: "jsonp",
         contentType: "application/json",
         async: false,
         url: "http://wld-api.eu1.frbit.net/index.php/api/v1/question",
         success: function(data){        
            alert(data);
         }
     });
```

In Firefox firebug (NET tab) the browser makes the call, returns a 200 OK response and all my JSON data. i can click through the Response and JSON tab and all my data is there.

So my question is....

WHY the hell doesn't success fire and alert my data? if i add

```
error: function(data){        
        alert(data);
     }
```

it does alert but firefox and everything else says it was a success?

Can anyone assist me at all?

i have just noticed in firebug in the console under errors it says

```
    SyntaxError: invalid label   -   "error":false,"question":[{"id":3,"question_title":"Question
```

And points to the error label? is this an issue that stops success fireing does anyone know.

Any advice / solution would make my day

Thanks Sam

Answer (score 2):

In order to use JSONP, you have to [tell Laravel to wrap the JSON in a callback function](http://four.laravel.com/docs/responses#special-responses):

```
return Response::json( $data )->setCallback( Input::get('callback') );
```

Next, you have to add the callback key to the query string:

```
$.ajax({
     type: "GET",
     dataType: "jsonp",
     contentType: "application/json",
     async: false,
     url: "http://wld-api.eu1.frbit.net/index.php/api/v1/question?callback=?",
     success: function(data){        
        alert(data);
     }
});
```

---

**Note:** you can use jQuery's [`$.getJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) method instead of `$.ajax()`. It's much more succinct:

```
$.getJSON("....../api/v1/question?callback=?").done(function ( data ) {
    alert( data );
});
```

Comment: Wow amazing thank you. i now wonder if there is an issue of the beta version of Laravel i am using as i get an error like

'Error: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Http\Response::setCallback() in /var/www/web/wld-api/htdocs/app/controllers/QuestionsController.php line 25' 

i will try and track this down unless you have an idea? it would appear setCallback() is an issue

Comment: @user1997198 - It works for me. [`Response::json()`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Response.php#L46-L54) returns a [`JsonResponse`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Http/JsonResponse.php) object, which extends [Symfony's `JsonResponse` class](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/JsonResponse.php), which in turn [implements `setCallback`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/JsonResponse.php#L64-L80).